# How do you select irregular duplicates with Google Sheets queries?

Tags: sql, google-apps-script, google-sheets, scripting, spreadsheet

I have a Google sheet with 186,000 rows. I have included a dummy spreadsheet to give you an idea of the data. I need to select ALL duplicates, that includes rows where the first names might not match (i.e. Cathy vs Catherine), but they still refer to the same individual. There are also instances where the addresses might be slightly different (like omitting "Ave" in one row but including it in another).

I need to write a query to account for all of these instances, including just regular duplicates. Or I could do multiple queries and just copy the results into one spreadsheet. In any case, I'm at a loss.

[Dummy spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQxT4.png). I have included one example of each case I am trying to account for (3 total).

Comment: Did I understand you correctly? Do you want to find all duplicate names, even those that look alike, such as Cathy and Catherine? If so, you might create the huge array of names, because how the script will understand that Cathy is Catherine but not Luigi?

Comment: I want to find duplicate rows. So the script would only add Cathy and Catherine if they share the same address. Ideally I would like to do something like match on the last name, first 3 characters of the first name, and first 5 characters of the address.

Comment: This would definetely call for some fuzzy logic, and I don't believe you'd ever get close to listing all duplicates, depending on the quality of your data.  Even if all the other criteria fields matched, you'd want Kathy, Catherine, Catharine, Cathy, etc, to be considered a match.  And you could have simple typos on the last name, eg. Mackay vs McKay, Williams or Willliams (3 "l"s).  And then typos in the address fields 111 Maple vs 11 Maple vs 111 Malpe.  You could come up with something that flags likely duplicates - two out of three fields an exact match, or other variations of that.

Comment: The data is all user-entered, so I'm assuming they all know how to spell their last name. The only "irregular" duplicate cases I have encountered are nickname vs full name, and omitting vs including the suffix in an address, which is why these are the only cases besides a perfect match that I am trying to account for.

Answer (score 0):

I have something that may be useful.  See my example sheet here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19h28go-nzunW6zexcMD61QjySUKJA3Q2Ci2Hu3OMuAg/edit?usp=sharing

Basically I build a key value for each record, along the lines you asked for.
All of the last name, part of the first name, part of the address, and the ZIP code.  Other variations are easily added.

The formula is just a string concatenation of parts of these fields, as follows:

```
=ArrayFormula(
  IF(ROW(A2:A)=2,"DupeKey",
    IF(A2:A<>"",A2:A &LEFT(B2:B,$N$1) &LEFT(G2:G,$N$1) &K2:K,"")))
```

A valuable option is to allow varying the length of the required matching sub-string, from the first name and address. This is controlled for the formula by selecting a substring length of 1 to 6 in cell N1, and seeing how this changes the duplicate records that are found.  The shorter the substring length, the more duplicate (or possibly duplicate) records will be found.

Conditional formating is used to highlight the duplicate records.
And you can use the column filters to sort by different data columns - to put all of the duplicates at the top, sort by column N, in Z-A order, and exclude blanks.

Note that this isn't perfect.  If someone accidentally types a space, or anything else, at the start of a data field, it will not be considered a duplicate.  Better logic would be required to catch those.

Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use these formulas:

- If cell B3 match "John" write "match", if doesn't match write "no"

`=IF(REGEXMATCH(B3,"John"), "match", "no")`

- If cell F2 contains content of cell B3, write "match", if doesn't match write "no"

`=IF(SEARCH(B3, F2)>0,"match","no")`

[image]

## References:

- [REGEXMATCH](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098292?hl=en-GB)
- [SEARCH](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094154?hl=en&ref_topic=3105625)